# Filter out folders from a user alert against a list

Tags: development, list, document-library, alert, user

I have created an alert for a user against a list (more specifically, a document library).

I want the user to be notified of all changes regarding list items (documents) and not any sub folders.

**What I've Tried:**

```
SPAlert alert = new SPAlert();
alert.Filter = "<Query><Neq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Text'>Folder</Value></Neq></Query>";
```

All items (including folders) are included in any e-mail alerts to the user.

To clarify, when a folder is created within a doc library with an alert against it - the user should not be notified.

When a document is created in that same document library, they should be.

I've also tried:

```
<Neq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Text'>Folder</Value></Neq>
```

(Note the `<Query>` tags have been omitted).

It is currently not an option to specify what content types I *do* want to include in the alert. I just want to omit any items of content type 'Folder'.

Comment: What if you used a search alert instead of a list alert. Could you make a search that returns just the docx files in a doc lib? if so create an alert on that search and see if it does the trick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you use a SPAlertHandler to change how alerts work for this list?  Then you can decide when an alert is sent or not in C# code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897791(v=office.14).aspx

```
public override bool OnNotification(SPAlertHandlerParams ahp)
{
    try
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(ahp.siteUrl + ahp.webUrl))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(ahp.webUrl))
            {
                ahp.headers["from"] = site.WebApplication.OutboundMailSenderAddress;  //Unsure if this is needed
                SPList list = web.Lists[ahp.a.ListID];
                SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(ahp.eventData[0].itemId);
                //SPAlert alert = web.Alerts[ahp.a.ID];

                if (item.Folder == null)  //Item is not a folder
                {
                    SPUtility.SendEmail(web, ahp.headers, ahp.body);  //Send Alert
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        //Handle error
    }
    return false;  //Tell SharePoint that the Alert is already processed
}
```

Comment: Steve this looks very very interesting. I'll read the link now, because up until now I've got no other approach to work. Thanks very much, +1. I'll mark accordingly.

Comment: I've added a bounty of 50 - I think it's well worth it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say you would try to filter by file type instead. The following would get you Word documents with file extension `docx` only:

```
<Where>

    <Eq>

        <FieldRef Name='File_x0020_Type' />

        <Value Type='text'>docx</Value>

    </Eq>

</Where>
```

Comment: There can't be a 'Where' tag in this CAML apparently. I can't really cater for the file type.

Comment: And if you loose the outer where, what happens then? *I guess there is an embedded <where> somewhere in your code, or in the object you're referencing*

Answer (score 0):

I went through this process myself (as you may have seen from my answer to your other question [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/59736/11647))

Basically, alert views can't be based on certain default content types. My full adventure figuring that out, as well as a work-around and some potentially helpful code, is [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55290/spv4-alerts-based-on-view-what-are-the-limitations) for those who are curious. It involves creating a custom content type based on the folder and changing all folders to that new content type, then filtering based on it.